# How to expose levels as attributes in a SSAS dimension using parent child hierarchy?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, parent-child, powerpivot

I'm working on a SSAS project.

One of my dimension table is "Catalog", containing a self-referencing relationship (parent child).

```
ID | PARENT_ID | NAME
1  | NULL      | A
2  | 1         | A1
3  | 1         | A2
4  | 2         | A11
...
```

I added my PARENT_ID attribute as "Parent" and ID as "Key".
I works well, I can browse my dimension as a tree.

Now, I need to be able to retrieve the name of the parents for each row.

```
LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | ... | NAME | NB
A      | A1     | A11    | ... | A111 | 10
...
```

So how to expose levels created by SSAS as attributes to be able to retrieve them in PowerPivot ?
I don't find how to do that...

Should I create a new hierarchy and to edit my view in order to get levels ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes "Parent usage for PARENT_ID and "Key" usage for ID. The tree works well.

Comment: If you can browse the dimension as a tree, you should be able to do the same in PowerPivot.   Is that not the case?

Comment: When I open a SSAS connection to my server through PowerPivot, I can filter my cube by selecting a node of the tree, I can drag and drop measures and the PARENT_ID attribute. It only displays the "NAME" field under PARENT_ID column. If I drag a level (from 1 to 8) it displays the same value for NAME.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I think your Parent_ID attribute is set up correctly, as ours behaves the same.   I think this is either a limitation of PowerPivot (or maybe a feature), or least it's a question about PowerPivot rather than SSAS.  Looks like you've done the SSAS part correctly.   Unfortunately, I am not an expert on PowerPivot.

Comment: You can write an MDX statement that gets the attribute and the level property. ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146048.aspx

Comment: I don't understand how to use these functions in my query. In fact, I would like to drag and drop autogenerated levels made by SSAS engine as attribute column in the SSAS import wizard. So how can I use MDX to add levels from my PARENT_ID attribute to my dataset?!